# C++: converting __int64 to unsigned long

Tags: c++, windows, int64

I'd like to use the following function in windows and linux, but I am not sure how to convert an __int64 to unsigned long. Is it safe to cast the value like I did?

```
getTimeInMilliseconds()
{
    #ifdef _WIN32


        static const __int64 magic = 116444736000000000; // 1970/1/1
        SYSTEMTIME st;
        GetSystemTime(&st);
        FILETIME   ft;
        SystemTimeToFileTime(&st,&ft); // in 100-nanosecs...
        __int64 t;
        memcpy(&t,&ft,sizeof t);
        return (unsigned long)((t - magic)/10000);
    #else
        struct timeval tv;
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        unsigned long s = tv.tv_sec * 1000;
        unsigned long us = tv.tv_usec / 1000;
        return s + us;
    #endif
}
```

Comment: In Windows `__int64` is 8 bytes wide but `unsigned long` is 4 bytes long. This question has no solution.

Comment: yes, until 03:14:07 UTC on Tuesday, 19 January 2038.

Comment: Right on my birthday :) I hope Windows will be long gone by 2038.

Comment: @Vlad It's *nix that you want rid of by 2038. The Y2K38 bug is a *nix problem not a Windows problem!  ;-)

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko: bio-computers, probably. On Windows... :-p

Comment: @David: WIndows uses 64bit numbers to represent time respect to it's API. Converting to unsigned long (or long) makes no sense.
Or better: maks sense respect to old Posix to Win16 mapping functions. But there is no more win16 today!

Comment: @Emilio I never said it made sense! I just pointed out the impossibility of converting `__int64` to `unsigned long`.

Comment: @David: sorry, I misunderstood your "no solution".
In fact I pointed out that the solution exist, but in another "domain".

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's "safe" in the sense that you can do, syntactically, what's written in the code. When downgrading a 64 bit int to a 32 bit long int, you naturally lose the top 32 bits, which isn't a problem if your value is small enough, the *problem* is that your value is not in fact small enough.

*both* definitions (WIN32 and not) are subject to overflow problems, not because you can't cast a 64 bit int to a long, but because you are trying to cram too large of a value into too small of a container.

Problem #1, the function name describes the result as "time in milliseconds" which is false, both implementations are attempting to return the result in *microseconds* (thousands of a second) not "milliseconds" which is millionths of a second. Decide what result you're actually shooting for and label it appropriately, reduce confusion in the long run. Note that the 100-nanosecond (billionth of a second) intervals is the same as 1/10th of a millisecond, which is 1/10,000th of a microsecond, just for reference.

Problem #2:
The "memcpy" to get the FILETIME struct into a long int is also wrong. FILETIME and __int64 have different byte alignments, and you'll get the bits in wrong places that way.
To turn a FILETIME into an _int64, you need to do this:

```
LARGE_INTEGER foo;
FILETIME baz;
__int64 bar;

foo.HighPart = baz.dwHighDateTime;
foo.LowPart = baz.dwLowDateTime;
bar = foo.Quadpart;
```

Problem #3:
a 32 bit long int can only store time values large enough to be useful *in seconds* and even then only until early in the year 2038, that's why "timeval" has a separate member for 'microseconds' it wasn't just to make your life hard.

If you want thousands of a second in a single value, you need at least 36 bits, probably more like 38-40 to have times that can refer to values in more robust time frame than 1970-2038. Since very few compilers have support for 40 bit integers, I would recommend just upgrading to a full 64 bits, unless for some reason you *can't* in which case you should come up with a better solution for what you're trying to do all around.

Comment: Just to clarify, I believe Siegurt's answer has milliseconds and microseconds the wrong way round, so there's nothing wrong with the naming of the function in question. 1 second = 1e3 milliseconds = 1e6 microseconds = 1e9 nanoseconds.

Comment: You have milli and micro seconds the wrong way round. [Microsecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) is 10-6 (i.e a millionth). [Millisecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) is 10-3 (i.e a thousandth)